# Create nodes and edges in python from a sql file

Tags: python, sql, networkx

Im trying to add nodes and edges from a sql file in python
but idont know how i do that !

I want to add the node and edges to a graphml file for use in GEPHI later on.

The first code creates the sql file from a text file.

```
import re
import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect('imdb1.db')
c = conn.cursor()

c.execute('''CREATE TABLE imdb1 (ROWID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, Title, Rating)''')

x = open("ratings.list.txt","r")
movread = x.readlines()
x.close()



#s = raw_input('Search: ').lower()
for ns in movread:


    if 'the lord of the' in ns.lower():
        d = re.split('\s+',ns,4)
        Title = d[4].rstrip()
        Rating= d[3]

        list = [Title,Rating]

       # print list
        # Insert a row of data
        c.execute('INSERT INTO imdb1 ( Title, Rating) values (?, ?)', (list[0],list[1]))
        conn.commit()
```

This should add nodes to the graph.

```
import networkx as nx
g=nx.Graph()

def add_node_tw(n, weight=None, time=None, source=None, location=None):
        if not g.has_node(n):
            screen_name=get_user_info(n)
            g.add_node(n)
            g.node[n]['weight']=1
            g.node[n]['Title']=Title

        else:
            g.node[n]['weight']+=1
```

This should add edges:

```
def add_edge_tw(n1,n2,weight=None):
    if not g.has_edge(n1,n2):
        g.add_edge(n1,n2)
        g[n1][n2]['weight']=1
    else:
        g[n1][n2]['weight']+=1
```

And the last part add edges and nodes from my sql file and puts it in a graphml file.

```
users = set()
for u in c:
    users.add(u['ROW_ID'])

g = nx.DiGraph()

for ROW_id in users:

    add_node_tw(R_id)

    for row in c.execute('SELECT * FROM imdb1 ORDER BY Rating'):
        print row

    for row in con.cursor():

        if row['ROWID'] in users:
            add_node_tw(row['ROWID'])
            add_node_tw(row['ROWID'], row['ROWID'])

nx.write_graphml(g,  '%s_graphml' % table)
```

I was trying to rewrite some code another guy made and come op with this i know it not finished at all but im trying to get on the right track but im not good at python and need alot of help. Thanks guys:)

Comment: It looks like you are not calling add_edge_tw?